# Parameterising cypress test cases

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress

I would like to run about 1000-2000 test cases which only differ in a parameter which is stored in a file. I tried to loop over those parameters in a single `describe` block:

```
describe('test', () => {
  params = require('... json');
  params.forEach(param => {
    if(`should do ${param}`, () => {
      // carry out test with param
    });
  });
});
```

but that doesn't work for thousands of tests (it's getting extremely slow up to the point where no test case executes at all (headless or headed mode)).

I tried to create multiple describe blocks with batches of the parameters, but that doesn't work either as now the assertions don't seem to hold any more (I think the specs/describe blocks run in parallel and the specified timeouts have already lapsed by the time the 2nd batch of describe test cases executes).

Is there any way to handle this? I could also imagine a parameterised call of the spec (with the `param`) via a script, but couldn't find a way to pass an argument to the spec from the command line into the `describe()` block.

Comment: Commenting on your last suggestion, you could get a variable from the command line to the test code by using environment variables. See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting then https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Command-Line